# How can I drop to byebug on MiniTest errors?

Tags: ruby, minitest, byebug

I'm using Ruby 2.0 with MiniTest. I'd like to drop to [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) if an error occurs during the test so that it can be easily debugged. Is it possible to override MiniTest's default action on error?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like minitest-debugger, but specific to byebug. Shouldn't be too difficult to create.

https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest-debugger

Comment: Yes, that'd be nice to have... and it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't helpful. The project you linked just overrides the `assert` method to drop to the debugger on assertion errors. I have tried, and it doesn't affect normal errors in any way. I'd have to override another method but I don't know which.

Comment: Ah, ok. So you want to drop to byebug on errors, not on failures. You could try catching the specific exception or using post-mortem mode

Comment: It looks that the OP was not asking for this, but someone just released [minitest-byebug](https://github.com/kaspth/minitest-byebug)! :)